# FsCheck, I am not getting `Prop.forAll` to work (F#)

Tags: f#, fscheck

I am not coming right with FsCheck, when I try and use `Prop.forAll`.

I have created two tests to demonstrate what I am doing, expecting them both to fail.

```fs
type Data = { value: int }

type NeverAOne =
    static member Data () =
        Arb.generate<int>
        |> Gen.filter (fun x -> x <> 1)
        |> Gen.map (fun x -> { value = x })
        |> Arb.fromGen

[<Property(Arbitrary = [| typeof<NeverAOne> |] )>] (* Fails *)
let ``Test One`` (x: Data) =
    x.value = 1

[<Fact>]
let ``Test Two`` () = (* Passes *)
    Prop.forAll (NeverAOne.Data ()) (fun x -> x.value = 1)
```

In this sample, *Test Two* passes. If I add breakpoints, I can see it is because no data is generated, so it iterates through 0 samples, which means none fail.

I am convinced that I am using `Prop.forAll` wrong, but though everything I have read through, I cannot find it.

Comment: I am referring to this blog post, and I still can't see that I am doing anything incorrectly. https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/08/ad-hoc-arbitraries-with-fscheckxunit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark the test as a plain Xunit `Fact` (rather than as a FsCheck `Property`), you have to explicitly check the property:

```ml
[<Fact>]
let ``Test Two`` () =
    let prop = Prop.forAll (NeverAOne.Data ()) (fun x -> x.value = 1)
    Check.QuickThrowOnFailure prop
```

The result I get is then:

```
System.Exception : Falsifiable, after 1 test (0 shrinks) (StdGen (74764374, 296947750)):
Original:
{ value = -2 }
```

Or you can just mark the test as a `Property`, of course:

```ml
[<Property>]
let ``Test Three`` () =
    Prop.forAll (NeverAOne.Data ()) (fun x -> x.value = 1)
```

Comment: So all I was doing was defining the property but never checking it.
I mistook `Prop.forAll` to be the test.

Comment: I assume from that, if I mark the test as `Property` I can return a Prop, a bool, or just not throw.

Comment: I think that's correct.